# Get max value of a column and id

Tags: sql, linq

I have the following columns in a table

MovieID - Point - CategoryID

1-5-1

1-6-2

1-4-3

2-7-1
...

As you can see there are more than one category for each movie. I want to find the movie with maximum points. But this points must be average of all categories. Following linq query finds me the max point like I want but I need  movieID too.

```
from tmp in
(from tmp in (
    (from Rating in db.Rating
    where
      Rating.DistrictID == 1
    group Rating by new {
      Rating.MovieID
    } into g
    select new {
      g.Key.MovieID,
      avg_point = (double?)g.Average(p => p.Point)
    }))
select new {
  tmp.avg_point,
  Dummy = "x"
})
group tmp by new { tmp.Dummy } into g
select new {
  max_point = (double?)g.Max(p => p.avg_point)
}
```

-------------------------------Answer
Thanks to @Sari Rahal. I come up with the following linq query:

```
(from tmp in (
    (from Rating in db.Rating
    where
      Rating.DistrictID == 1
    group Rating by new {
      Rating.MovieID
    } into g
    select new {
      g.Key.MovieID,
      avg_point = (double?)g.Average(p => p.Point)
    }))
orderby
  tmp.avg_point descending
select new {
  tmp.MovieID,
  tmp.avg_point
}).Take(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this simply by Order By and Limit.  You order by the MovieID and Limit to 1 will give you the Information of the movie with the most points.  Don't forget to change it to ascending or descending depending on your preference and how your scale works.

```
Select MovieID, Point Ordery By MovieID Limit 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your inner query should be enough just call `Max()` after the average.

```
from Rating in db.Rating
where
  Rating.DistrictID == 1
group Rating by new {
  Rating.MovieID
} into g
select new {
  g.Key.MovieID,
  avg_point = (double?)g.Average(p => p.Point).Max()
}
```